# How to check list_display if no value, to show -- in django admin?

Tags: python, django, list, django-admin, display

Django ver 1.10

How can I conditionally check if a variable is blank and show "-"?

i.e if `get_followers` and/or `get_following` are not set, display "-"

```
@admin.register(Application)
class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = [
        'name',
        'get_following',
        'get_followers',
        'get_friends',
        'manager',
       ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation for list_display:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

You can use methods for this. For example:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    following = ...
    followers = ...
    friends = ...

    def get_following(self):
        if not self.following:
            return "-"
        return self.following
```

and in your admin.py you simply put the name of the method

```
@admin.register(Application)
class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  list_display = [
        'name',
        'get_following',
        ...
       ]
```

Comment: Works perfect. The only thins is that I get <QuerySet [<variable name:value>]>. Not sure how to get rid of extra words like query set. I think I missing something. But your solutions works perfect.

Comment: @Stryker if you show me your Application model class I can help you.

Comment: Here it is if you can get to it. https://gist.github.com/dariushazimi/e00375174f99dd763bf2012e00a35e92

Comment: Yep, I can see it. So you want to display in your admin a list, like relationships or ?

Comment: Relationship is fine. The issue is , when there is a value in list display, it displays it like <queryset[value]> instead of just values. I think the issue is in return string or something

Comment: For example, if you have class: 
class Example(models.Model):
     category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
def get_categories(self):
        return ", ".join([x.name for x in self.category.all()])
you can use method like this